# how to model bind form urlencoded data to .net class

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a 3rd party vendor posting data to us in the following format.  Unfortunately this is the only format they offer.  Json would be nice, but we don't have a choice.  It's hitting a .net core webapi controller method.

```
contact%5Bid%5D=2&contact%5Bemail%5D=test@test.com&contact%5Bfirst_name%5D=john&contact%5Blast_name%5D=smith
```

The controller method looks like this.

```
public IActionResult Endpoint([FromForm] customClass)
{
    //do something with customClass
    return Ok();
}
```

The class would be something like

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Domain.Models.Custom
{
    [DataContract]
    public class CustomClass
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "contact[id]")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "contact[first_name]")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "contact[last_name]")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "contact[phone]")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "contact[email]")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

From everything I've read it sounds like decorating the class with the DataContract and DataMember attributes should to the model binding for me.  But when I look at the instance of customClass in the Endpoint method all the properties are null.

Comment: Neither `DataContract` nor `DataMember` are required. All You need is `[FromForm]` on the action param you're bind to, and all the property names need to line up. And, there lies your problem. Plain and simple, you can't bind directly via what's being provided. About the only thing you can do is just accept it as a string or a FormCollection and then manually build your class by parsing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

DataContract / DataMember attributes are not supported by default when using the `FromForm` binding.  They are only supported with `FromBody` as you'd expect because the serializer used (typically JSON.NET) supports these attributes - but that support is independent of MVC binding.

There is a way to extend MVC's form binding during startup:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new DataMemberBindingMetadataProvider()));
```

Simple implementation of `IBindingMetadataProvider` to look for the DataMemberAttribute / Name:

```
public class DataMemberBindingMetadataProvider : IBindingMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateBindingMetadata(BindingMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        var dataMember = context.Attributes.OfType<DataMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (dataMember != null)
        {
            context.BindingMetadata.BinderModelName = dataMember.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could try adding `DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider` instead of your own metadata provider, however I found that its constructor dependencies make this problematic.